# android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" changes the height of Dialog Activity from wrap_content to match_parent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog, android-relativelayout, android-wrap-content

I have a `Button` inside an `Activity` with `Dialog` style. 
Here is xml file of my `Activity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the style of my `Activity` which causes to show it as a `Dialog`

```
<style name="Modal" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

This `Activity` show as full screen even though the `android:windowFullscreen` is false! and when I remove the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` from the `Activity` xml file, the `height` of `Activity` changed to `wrap_content` and there is no problem. I want to know how can I solve this problem without removing the attribute of `Button`.

Here you can see the result of showing Activity

with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

[image]

and with out `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate the exact problem?

Comment: I want to have an Activity with Dialog style. it's OK and I can start Activity with dialog style successfully as you can see in my screenshots. My problem is height of this activity which is match_parent instead of wrap_content! I want the second screenshot with setting android:layout_alignParentBottom to "true". because in another situation I want to start this Activity without Dialog style and if I remove this attribute my Button doesn't locate at the bottom of screen. Is it clear enough? @M.WaqasPervez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting attribute

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

programmatically using the below code

```
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
    Button button = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.button);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, view.getId());
    button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

in your xml file you need to set a **id attribute**  and remove **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You are right. It seems this is the better way to deal with this problem! But I wished the `RelativeLayout` handle this problem itself in some way.

Comment: I will try to figure it out and will let u know.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the `FrameLayout` instead?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Button" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks to your guidance. 
I have a complex layout and I want to solve this problem with RelativeLayout rather than change the layout root.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this runtime when you create dialog...

```
mDialog.show();
Window window = mDialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

As i did in my case...
May it help @Nava

Comment: As I said I have an Activity with Dialog style. I tested your code after setContentView() method in my Activity class. unfortunately this didn't work for me!